# Does an equivalent of Wi-Fi Direct/Wi-Fi P2P exist for Phonegap/Cordova?

Tags: android, cordova, wifi-direct, wifip2p

I'm building an Android application to allow communication between two devices in a limited range but I can't find an equivalent plugin to the native [Android Wi-Fi peer-to-peer](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p.html) for Phonegap/Cordova.

Any suggestion ? May another service (such as the [Google's WebRTC](http://www.webrtc.org/)) do the trick ? Is going native the solution ?

Comment: did you ever find a solution?

Comment: No and I'm still interested in knowing the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same problem but there is a plugin called "thali" which I haven't tested it yet but here is the link anyway if you want to give it ago. 
let us know how you getting on

https://www.npmjs.com/package/thali

Comment: Thali mentions in its github that it is NOT production worthy yet